# Make crawlers index content that is added to page with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I request some data from my api using JQuery, adding to the page once I receive a valid response.

However, I am concerned that this content will not be scraped by any indexing engines.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: They will scrape it, the bots are designed to run headless and use scripts. However you may be non-compliant.

Comment: Non-compliant as in you'll get a SEO error cause items are popping up as the page loads making accidental clicks go right up. Cheers hope that helps, check your google search console most robots run like that.

Comment: SEO is not a topic for SO -> [Where to find answers to SEO questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281367/where-to-find-answers-to-seo-questions) -> https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Definitely not but the question was if the bots could read their script. Answer is yes!

Comment: @BGPHiJACK The follow-up questions will all be SEO-related. And if "yes" is really enough as answer the question should not have been asked in the first place -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) - Either way -> off-topic for SO